# TextField value when tried to get in javascript using jQuery is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to get a value from a textField onclick of submit button to a javascript function and trying to alert the same to the user. I am using JSP and Jquery(in javascript) for this.

JSP -

```
<input id="employeeName" type="text" name="empName" value=ben/> 
<input type="button" value="search employee" onclick="abc();" />
```

JAVASCRIPT -

```
function abc() {
   var typedEmployee = $('#employeeName').val();
   alert(typedEmployee );
}
```

Problem - when i execute this, i get typedEmployee value "" and the alert is empty.

I have also tried using -

```
var typedEmployee = document.getElementById('employeeName').value;
```

Still the same issue.

I have used this method before and that works fine.

Could someone help me out with this please???

Answer (score 1):

This little bit of jQuery works.

```
<input id="employeeName" type="text" name="empName" value="ben" /> 
<input type="button" id="getName" value="search employee" />
```

Remove the `onClick` from before and add an `id="getName"` to the `button`

Place the following in the `head` section of your page.

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#getName').click(function(){
        var typedEmployee = $('#employeeName').val();
        alert(typedEmployee);
    });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT** - Code above changed to show how to place on the page

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/dkQFq/

Comment: I added this jquery code outside the function, firebug says that $ is not defined. but i do have the jquery imports. when i tried this inside the function, it doesn't do anything and no error in firebug. Thanks

Comment: @Sara.  make sure you add the `id="getName"` to the `button` and that you place the jQuery code in a `document.ready` function inside `script` tags in the `head` section of your page.  So `<script type="text/Javascript">$(document).ready(function(){//ANSWER CODE HERE//});</script>`

Comment: Did the same thing as you have asked me to, i get a blank alert.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the single quote from the beginning of both input type ans see if it works.

Comment: Hi samir, iam not using the single quote in my code. it was not visible in this page when i wrote this question. Just to make it visible here, i had to add the quote. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to put value ben under quotes & remove the single quote.

Your jquery works just fine in my FF 5.0

Try this:

```
<input id="employeeName" type="text" name="empName" value="ben" /> 
<input type="button" value="search employee" onclick="abc();" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function abc() {
   var typedEmployee = $('#employeeName').val();
   alert(typedEmployee );

   typedEmployee = document.getElementById('employeeName').value;
   alert('employee = ' + typedEmployee);
}
```

Comment: Hi,  I tried this but still getting the same blank alert. The same thing works fine in another jsp page.

Comment: I updated the code. Added your second js print. What do you see if you try this? If still an issue, do a view source on the page and see what is the html...

Comment: I tried ur suggestion, first alert is empty, second one says - employee =

Comment: Type something in the textbox. This is starnge. You try another browser to see if anything different. The second one is just pure js.

Comment: I have tried in IE8 and FF5. Gave input in the field, still the same thing happens... :(